# How to lock the default choice without giving any options in DJANGO

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I've been working with a model with has one the field as a choice field and multiple choices are provided.

For eg->

The gender field is a choice field where users can choose from a drop down menu.

- But in a certain case, I only want the form to be open to female candidates, so the choices won't be shown, and the field will automatically be set as 'female' in the backend.

How can I do this?

Here are the code snippets from my code ->

// models.py

```
class RegisterUser(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES= (
        (
            constants.MALE,
            constants.MALE_STR,
        ),
        (constants.FEMALE, constants.FEMALE_STR),
        (
            constants.OTHERS,
            constants.OTHERS_STR,
        ),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    college = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gender = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default=constants.MALE
    )
```

// form.py

```
class RegsiterForm(forms.Form):


    gender = forms.ChoiceField(
        label="Select Gender (default is Male)",
        widget=forms.Select(
            attrs={"class": "form-control", "placeholder": "Select Gender"}
        ),
        choices=GENDER_CHOICES,
    )
```

// views.py

```
@login_required
def publish_app_without_apk(request, **kwargs):
    template_name = "registerform.html"
    context = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data.get("name")
            age = request.POST.get("age")
            college = request.POST.get("college")
            gender = request.POST.get("gender")
```

Answer (score 0):

So, what you can do for those certain forms is not to load the form field on the front-end, once the user submits the form you can set the gender field to the specific gender for which the form was loaded.
Let say you are loading the form for "Female", then you will only load form fields like "name, age, college". Once the user submits the form set the gender at the backend since the form is only for females like this...

```
@login_required
def publish_app_without_apk(request, **kwargs):
    template_name = "registerform.html"
    context = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form_data = form.save(commit=False)
            form_data.name = form.cleaned_data.get("name")
            form_data.age = request.POST.get("age")
            form_data.college = request.POST.get("college")
            form_data.gender = "Female"
            form_data.save()
        else:
             'Some code'
```